# Calculation Overload from Excel to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

How can I convert this Excel Formula to SharePoint?

```
=IF(AND(F6="REG",G6>=4,G6<8),0.5,IF(AND(F6="REG",$G6>=8,G6<=16),1,IF(AND(F6="HDY",G6>=4,G6<8),1,IF(AND(F6="HDY",G6>=8,G6<16),1.5,0))))
```

Is there a way to convert this excel calculation to SharePoint?

Comment: Do you want to convert this Excel formula with SharePoint List Columns?

Answer (score 0):

Create a column F6(Single line of text)

Create a column G6(Number)

Create a column calculate(Calculated) with the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(F6="REG",G6>=4,G6<8),0.5,IF(AND(F6="REG",G6>=8,G6<=16),1,IF(AND(F6="HDY",G6>=4,G6<8),1,IF(AND(F6="HDY",G6>=8,G6<16),1.5,0))))
```

[image]